# Symfony REST API form collection with many-to-many entities

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to make a Symfony form with a many-to-many relationship using hidden entities. With [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bjo3rnf/4061232), my form connects plain IDs to entity objects, and has worked quite well for the REST API I'm building. The problem is how to create a form to receive and connect multiple entities when the embedded entity is only a single ID.

For example,

```
Employee
    $id - primary key int
    $name
    $companies - many-to-many relationship

Company
    $id - primary key int
    $name
    $employees - inverse many-to-many relationship
```

Now I want to receive a POST request with this content

```
name = "Employee 1"
companies[] = 1
companies[] = 2
```

You can see that the company form only contains integers that map to existing companies. A normal [Symfony collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) assumes that you're joining another object together with new properties, like name, email or phone number, but in this case the ID is the only item to match.

How can I configure a collection form type to take in only an ID and still work without web forms?

Answer (score 1):

> A normal Symfony collection assumes that you're joining another object together with new properties, like name, email or phone number, but in this case the ID is the only item to match.

Actually it does not. The [`CollectionType`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) field can be paired with [`IntegerType`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/integer.html) so you would get a collection of integers:

```
->add('companies', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => IntegerType::class,
    'allow_add' => true,
])
```

After that you may apply validation that checks if what passed is a collection of integers:

```
/**
 * @Assert\All(
 *     @Assert\Type(type="integer")
 * )
 * @var integer[]
 */
public $companies;
```

Comment: Look, You helped me very much last night, I just want to say thanks again.